# MSBuild not compiling MSTest projects (from TeamCity)

Tags: msbuild, mstest, teamcity

Im using MSBuild 10 to compile a .Net solution file which includes a MSTest project. Im using MSBuild from within TeamCity.

MSBuild doesnt seem to be building the test project and so the test project dll isnt created for use by MSTest, although the other projects are compiled OK.

What do I need to do to get the test project to compile or should I be doing something else?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET 4.0 is not fully supported by TeamCity. Please check toolversion in your script.

Comment: I've got the 2010 solution compiling with MSBuild by setting the MSBuild environment variable to the 2010 version and using the sln2008 build runner. But the test projects arent compiled ...

The build runner is executing MSTest for 2010 OK but the compiled binaries for the test projects arent there.

Comment: Solution 2008 build runner will set toolVersion to 3.5. But to compile all .NET 4.0 projects it should be set to 4.0. 
Consider creating wrapping msbuild script.

Could you please provide sample VS2010 solution for me to reproduce the case at teamcity-feedback@jetbrains.com

Comment: for anyone running across this, .NET 4.0 is now supported by TeamCity 5.1 RC.

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to configure the build agent to build off the solution file (sln). The solution file should include the test project and everything gets compiled.
Ask if this does not answer your question.